# How to add a delete button in the html table to delete entire row from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have created a table to fetch and display data from the table. I want to add a delete button to each row on the table so that when clicked on the delete button the entire row is deleted from the HTML table as well as the database. Tried several ways but didn't work out.

```
    <div class="container mt-3 ml-3">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>S.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Rating</th>
        <th>Review</th>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Suggestion</th>
        <th>NPS</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-warning">

<?php
include 'database_conn.php';      // makes db connection

$sql = "SELECT feedbackID, name, email, rating, review, image, suggestion, nps
        FROM feedback 
        ORDER BY feedbackID Desc";
$queryResult = $dbConn->query($sql);

// Check for and handle query failure
if($queryResult === false) {
    echo "<p>Query failed: ".$dbConn->error."</p>\n";
    exit;
}
// Otherwise fetch all the rows returned by the query one by one
else {
    if ($queryResult->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($rowObj = $queryResult->fetch_object()) {
            echo "<tr>
                  <td>{$rowObj->feedbackID}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->name}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->email}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->rating}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->review}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->image}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->suggestion}</td>
                  <td>{$rowObj->nps}</td>
                  

              ";
        }

    }
}
?>

</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: just add a delete button with hyperlink like <a href=deletedata.php?id={$rowObj->feedbackID}>Delete</a> . Then in the deletedata.php, execute the delete query

Comment: There is no such thing as phpMyAdmin table or database. It's a tool to access MySQL databases, not an actual database.